# Determining whether a Google Play one time product is active (IAB)

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

We are facing with some sort of interesting scenario. On one of our production apps, a user came to us that they've bought the app before and even then, they cannot use the premium features.

In our app, we used IAP (Google Play Billing library, not IABHelper) with one-time product method: We let the user buy the app, and then never consumed the product. The method we're following is: After reading some questions here and examining documentation, I've found out that `BillingClient.queryPurchases(INAPP)` scans the purchases **locally** and any inactive products are not there, and due to them being not there, if premium features are active, we're disabled it.

`BillingClient.queryPurchaseHistoryAsync(INAPP, listener)` returns **all** products whether they are active or not, but the product is not a subscription so `Purchase.isAutoRenewing()` is always false.

Here is the problem: If we wipe out Google Play's data or reset the phone and download the app again, since the data in Google Play is deleted, `BillingClient.queryPurchases(INAPP)` returns an empty list, even if the user bought the app before. In this scenario, `BillingClient.queryPurchaseHistoryAsync(INAPP, listener)` method seems to be useful but, it does not contain any information about whether the product is **active** or **refunded**.

Final case is, we need to consume the product if it is refunded to close premium features (or activate them since there is no local information) but there is no data that the product is bought and fetching data from API itself with `queryPurchaseHistoryAsync` does not contain any information about the product is active or not, it's just there, represents that it has been bought before. So how should we know if somebody bought this product and not get a refund?

Comment: The first thing you need is a web server of your own. As Google suggests "It's highly recommended to validate purchase details on a server that you trust. If you cannot use a server, however, it's still possible to validate these details within your app on a device."

Comment: Then you can handle consumption related queries to your backend server and get the latest status of the product.